# PHP Regex Recursive - ERROR UNDEFINED

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I have these lines of code in php..

```
$ALL2 = "($SUM|$DIFF|$PROD|$QUOT|$MOD|$MAX|$MIN|$VAR_NAME|$LIT_NUMBAR|$LIT_NUMBAR)";
$SUM2 = "$OPERATOR_SUM $ALL2|$SUM2 ($INFIX) $ALL2|$SUM2";
```

I plan on using recursive code on the 2nd line but the problem is..$SUM2 in Right Hand Side will be undefined..

How will i make the code run?

Help will be very much appreciated..

Comment: Is `$SUM` defined anywhere else?

Comment: Recursive variable references in PHP strings do not work. You will need to look into the actual pcre [recursions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) and preferrably [named subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

Comment: $SUM2 is...$SUM is used in earlier lines...

Comment: @mario so, there is no other way to implement recursion by variables?

Comment: @vaizaren: if you changed the single to double quotes, the parser wouldn't set about trying to resolve all `$[a-z]` to variables. If this supposed to happen, and you're trying to get this into a working regex, try using `preg_quote`, too

Answer (score 0):

I used pcre [recursions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) and named [subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) as suggested and it was better.